# JMeter: How to insert server name/IP dynamically in HTTP Request

Tags: csv, jmeter, server

I have created JMeter script that need to be used for different environments like Staging, Production, etc. I want to dynamically change the IP address.

Can someone let me know how can I proceed with this?

Comment: Please check this - http://www.testautomationguru.com/jmeter-manage-test-plan/

Answer (score 1):

- Remove all the IP, port, protocol details from the `HTTP Sampler`.
- Add `HTTP Request Defaults` under test plan - in which you can update IP, Port & Protocol details. So, just changing it one place will do for entire test.
- As you need to change it dynamically, use property file/properties. for example.. (these names can be anything)

  ```
  host.ip=10.11.12.13
  host.port=443
  host.protocol=https
  ```
- You can pass the properties via command line argument to the test.

  ```
  jmeter -n -t /path/to/test.jmx  -l /path/to/result.jtl -Jhost.ip=10.111.12.13 -Jhost.port=443 -Jhost.protocol=https -Jtest.duration=300
  ```

  `J - defines a local JMeter property.`

In the test, access these values using `${__P(host.ip)}`,`${__P(host.port)}`..etc

---

If you have a lot of properties, You can have a look at the `Property File Reader`. I have been using this for a while & I love it.

Advantage is - even in the GUI mode, it will work great.

http://www.testautomationguru.com/jmeter-property-file-reader-a-custom-config-element/

If you use the `Property File Reader` & pass the property file name itself dynamically, then use

```
jmeter -n -t /path/to/test.jmx  -l /path/to/result.jtl -Jproperty.file.path=/path/to/file.properties
```

Then access it using `${__P(property.file.path)}` in the `File Path`.